# Voice recognition while receiving call

Tags: java, android

When the phone rings, I want to mute the ringing sound and to start the voice recognition in android. I tried to implement it using the attached code, however it doesn't work for me.

What can I change in order that this code will work?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class receivecall extends BroadcastReceiver {
private int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
Toast toast;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                toast = Toast.makeText(context,phoneNumber+"call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);               
           toast.show();
               Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
               i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                       RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
               i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
               context.startActivity(i); 

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.handsfree.IncomingCallInterceptor: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.handsfree.IncomingCallInterceptor
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.handsfree.IncomingCallInterceptor
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
10-05 14:51:50.384: E/AndroidRuntime(559):  ... 10 more
10-05 14:51:52.113: I/Exception(538): PhoneStateListener() e = android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
10-05 14:52:00.145: I/Process(559): Sending signal. PID: 559 SIG: 9
10-05 14:52:01.553: W/TextToSpeech(538): shutdown failed: not bound to TTS engine
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538): Activity com.example.handsfree1.HandsFree has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@412b7590 that was originally bound here
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.handsfree1.HandsFree has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@412b7590 that was originally bound here
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:936)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:830)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1117)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:370)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:614)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:584)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:547)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:522)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:507)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at com.example.handsfree1.HandsFree.onCreate(HandsFree.java:82)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-05 14:52:03.134: E/ActivityThread(538):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: start by saying what doesn't work.

Comment: hi,it doesnt start the voice recognition when i receive call...i want that the voice recognition should be invoked automatically while phone is ringing.

Comment: do you receive the broadcast, to begin with ?

Comment: i added a toast to my code and it really show me the phoneNumber of the caller in Toast,so i receive the broadcast and it works good,so i dont think that here is my problem,maybe do you see another problem with my code?

Comment: there is probably an error, you should post the stack trace. the error is most likely telling you precisely what to do, which is to add a NEW_TASK flag in your intent.

Comment: hi i didnt understand you,where should i add this NEW_TASK flag?thanks alot for help

Comment: post the stacktrace of the error during the startActivity

Comment: hi, i cant post the stacktrace because the voice recognize doesnt work on the android emulator...i installed my app on the phone and when i call my phone it doesnt active the voice recognition when the phone rings...i also added a NEW_TASK  flag and it doesnt work...maybe someone has another fix for this?thanks alot

Comment: can't you getthe stacktrace from your hpne?

Comment: how can i get the stacktrace from my android phone?i know that i can get the stacktrace  from eclipse,not from a real phone

Comment: a little search will give you the answer

Comment: hi i added it to the main post,i hope that this is what that you mean

Comment: there seem to be soemthing wrong with the package name of your intercept thingy

Comment: i really dont know how to solve this problem..when i receive a call it doesnt prompt the voice recognition...someone in this forum has antoher idea how to solve this problem?thanks in advance

Comment: your package is sometimes named handsfree1 and sometimes handsfree. also, there is nothing that reacts to android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH on your device